# golang, how satisfy interface from many files in same package?

Tags: go, interface

I have this logic of my app:

```
myapp/
     |- tables/
              |-table1.go
              |-table2.go
              |-table3.go
      - main.go
```

In main.go I have simple interface:

```
type DBInterface interface {
    DataParse(string) string
}
```

Now, table1, table2, tableN are name of tables in DB. I need to perform specific action on specific table. Hence, in table1.go I have simple function which returns parsed data for table1.go, some for the rest.

Now, problem is that I have in main.go function:

```
func ParseDataFromManyTables(dbs DBInterface) {
    // some actions on tables like: dbs.DataParse("tablename")
    // and these DataParse() are declared in tables/table*.go
}
```

What I wanted to do is to use function which satisfies interface from each tables/table*.go file (DataParse()). But the problem is - this function cannot be redeclared in same package (tables here), what I can do better here? I know, that I may create new packages(directories) but I does not seem to be correct approach here....

Comment: What do you mean by "this function cannot be redeclared in same package"? Do you define any types and make them implement `DBInterface`?

Comment: Why you want to declare multiple functions with same name? What's the difference between them? You question seems you only have one `ParseDataFromManyTables` that parses any table you pass to it.

Comment: you can create receivers for each table func by its name, receiver can be of any type . And call your func using that

Answer (score 1):

You cannot satisfy an interface with a function. Only types with methods can satisfy an interface.

To satisfy an interface you need to declare a type and then implement a set of methods on that type that match the method signatures of the interface's method set.

In you case you can declare a type in each of your files and for each of those types implement a method that has the same signature as `DBInterface`'s `ParseData`:

`table1.go`

```
package tables

type Table1 struct{}

func (t Table1) DataParse(s string) string {
    // ...
    return "..."
}
```

`table2.go`

```
package tables

type Table2 struct{}

func (t Table2) DataParse(s string) string {
    // ...
    return "..."
}
```

Given this example you can now pass a value of type `Table1` or `Table2` to `ParseDataFromManyTables`.